# How can I prove that $f$ is continuous except at $(0,0)$, $\int f(x,y)\,dx\,dy=0$ but $\int f(x,y)\,dy\,dx=1$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> For $i=1,2,3,\dots\ $ let $\varphi_i\in C(\Bbb R)$ have support in
>   $(2^{-i},2^{1-i})$, such that $\int\varphi_i=1$.
>
> Put :
>
> $$f(x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\left[\varphi_i(x)-\varphi_{i+1}(x)\right]\varphi_i(y)$$
>
> Then $f$ has compact support in $\Bbb R^2$, $f$ is
>   continuous except at $(0,0)$, $\int f(x,y)\,dx\,dy=0$ and 
>   $\int f(x,y)\,dy\,dx=1$.

Proving that $f$ has a compact support is done, but how can I see that $f$ is continuous except at $(0,0)$, $\int f(x,y)\,dx\,dy=0$ and $\int f(x,y)\,dy\,dx=1$?

Comment: Can you show that the series is locally uniformly convergent in $\mathbb{R}^2/ 0$?

Comment: Given any $x$, note that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\varphi_n(x) = 0$ due to the compact support hypothesis.  Then observe that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(\varphi_i(x) - \varphi_{i+1}(x)) = \varphi_1(x) - \lim_{n\to\infty}\varphi_n(x) = \varphi_1(x)$ since the series telescopes.  From this, and that $\int\varphi_1(x)dx = 1$, you should be able to see why $\int f(x,y)dydx = 1$.